# check_keys=False for insert_one() or insert_many() in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The older version of PyMongo had a check_keys=False which enables me to have '$' or '.' in the keys. I also understand it is not recommended by MongoDB to have such characters in the keys which would in the affect filtering, but is there a check_keys=False for insert_one() or insert_many() the bypass_validation does not seem to do the trick